# Как достать с базы wordpress аторов с найбольшим количеством подписчиков?

Tags: mysql

вот этот запрос выбирает лучших авторов ,а как достать авторов с большим количеством подписчиков ,подскажите?

```
SELECT object_author, SUM(rating_value) as total_rating
FROM wp_rcl_rating_values as ratingusers
WHERE rating_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND object_author != '0'
GROUP BY object_author
ORDER BY total_rating DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

и этот код получает подписчиков //считаем кол-во подписчиков указанного пользователя

```
    return RQ::tbl( new Rcl_Feed_Query() )->where( [
    'object_id' => $user_id,
    'feed_type' => 'author',
    'feed_status' => 1
    ] )->get_count( 'feed_id', 'cache' );


$this->define( 'RCL_PREF', $wpdb->base_prefix . 'rcl_' );


class Rcl_Feed_Query extends Rcl_Query {
    function __construct( $as = false ) {

        $table = array(
            'name'   => RCL_PREF . "feeds",
            'as'     => $as ? $as : 'rcl_feeds',
            'cols'   => array(
                'feed_id',
                'user_id',
                'object_id',
                'feed_type',
                'feed_status'
            )
        );

        parent::__construct( $table );
    }

}

    function get_count( $field_name = false, $cache = false ) {
            return ( ! $result = $this->get_operator_data( 'COUNT', $field_name, $cache ) ) ? 0 : $result;
        }
```

это диаграмма базы подписчики думаю в таблице feed
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Количество подписчиков считается с помощью функции COUNT(). А со связями в этой простыне пусть кто-нить ещё разбирается.

Comment: добавил функцию function get_count(  в вопрос

Comment: а можно включить связи в DBforge?

Comment: *добавил функцию function get_count( в вопрос* Это функция к MySQL и близко не лежала, это какой-то фреймворк...

Comment: это можно из этих функций сложить MYSQL запрос?

Comment: частично сделал SELECT wp_rcl_feeds.feed_id , wp_rcl_feeds.user_id,wp_rcl_feeds.object_id,wp_rcl_feeds.feed_type,wp_rcl_feeds.feed_status
  FROM wp_rcl_feeds
  WHERE wp_rcl_feeds.feed_type = 'author' AND wp_rcl_feeds.feed_status = 1
  GROUP BY wp_rcl_feeds.user_id
     ORDER BY CAST(wp_rcl_feeds.object_id as DECIMAL) DESC